# My API returns me 1 instead of JSON object

Tags: java, spring, boot

I am using Spring Boot to build a simple API that retrieves an object named MutualFund.
I have a get request that returns a MutualFund object. As I tested this method using postman, I receive a 200 status and a value of 1 in the response body. Literally a 1. Not in quotes. The value 1

I want the MutualFund object to be shown in the response body like:

```
{
"name": "someFund",
"price": 2.00
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class MutualFundController {

    @Autowired
    MutualFundRepo repo;

    @GetMapping("/mutualFundNav/{name}")
    MutualFund getMutualFundByName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return repo.findByName(name);
    }

}
```

Quick tip, the URL I use for the GET request is

```
localhost:8080/mutualFundNav/BenjaminFranklin
```

In my case, "BenjaminFranklin" is the name of the mutual fund

Comment: The "1" you are seeing is probably the line number from Postman, not actual data

Comment: You're correct. If that's the case, then where is my JSON object to be found? It's missing

Comment: Does MutualFund have getters/setters?

Comment: I've added them now. It's still not working correctly

Comment: When I debug, i get a "null" back

Comment: Actually it's working. Turns out my fault was not using a space between BenjaminFranklin. The name should've been Benjamin Franklin

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the mistake by using a space between BenjaminFranklin. Like this:

```
localhost:8080/mutualFundNav/Benjamin Franklin
```

I was unaware that my API returns a 200 when an object is null. I thought the object existed, and I assumed the mistake occurred due to the controller

The object is saved like this:

```
MutualFund mutualFund1 = new MutualFund("Benjamin Franklin", 250.00);
```